# Ionic 2 how to retrieve info in list?

Tags: ionic2

I'm trying to retrieve the info from my PHP server.

Here is my code

```
//Dans mon service d'authentification
checkVehicleList() {
    this.getUserId().then(data => {
    this.userid = data; 
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        alert(this.userid);
        this.http.get('http://localhost/helloworld/api/v1/list?iduser='+this.userid).subscribe(data => {
            alert(data.json().InformationsVehicules);
           if(data.json().InformationsVehicules){
                alert("reussite");
           } else { alert("error !") }
             });
        });
    });
}

//Dans la page des vehicules, j'appel la fonction juste pour savoir ce qu'elle qaffiche avec les alerts
public MarqueVeh : any;
public marque : any;

loadVeh() {
  this.viauth.checkVehicleList().then(data => {
    this.MarqueVeh = data;
  });
}


// Voici le tableau que me retourne ma route PHP
{"InformationsVehicules":[{"marque":"bgy","matricule":"ce1370","numero_chassi":"123654"},{"marque":"bvd","matricule":"derty","numero_chassi":"ddff"}]}
```

I want the array that is returned to be kept in a variable so that I can use it like this

```
<ion-button button round class="veh-button" clear color="light" (click)="showVehiclePopUp()">{{Veh.marque}}<span style="display:inline-block; width: 200px;"></span>

<ion-buttons end>
  <ion-icon name="ios-play"></ion-icon>
</ion-buttons></button><br>
```

I put the alerts in my code to know what the variables contain and I receive as message "undefiened".

Comment: Does the PHP server return data or not? What do you get when you console log the subscription data?

Comment: my PHP server return data but my function not get the data. Sorry I do not have a very good english

Comment: Don't worry, your english is fine.

Comment: OK, please help me